# как поменять цвет svg файла на react/jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

как поменять цвет такого svg изображения и можно ли это вообще сделать при том что оно было преобразовано из png в svg? https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hypatia-t01nz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: из png в svg ?  это реально работает ?

Comment: да, это очень даже работает

Comment: у вас в вашем кодесанбокс обычное изображение завёрнутое в тег svg

Comment: так а каким всеже свойством можно поменять цвет? Fill пробывал и не вышло

Comment: так что сменить заливку в вашем случае можно только с помощью графических редакторов типа фотошоп гимп крита паинт.нет  и т д

Comment: ну разумеется fill не будет работать так как это заливает контур path rect circle а там обычное изображение в теге image

Comment: а ваще эта схема ни всегда работает даже у convertio.co